# Trying understand purpose of the "kind" object in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm in the process of upgrading a NodeJS application from v4.X to v8.X that uses PassportJS. Compounding my problem is the fact that I'm new to Passport and I'm rebuilding the app inside of a Docker container. The app relies on a [Passport-WindowsAuth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) to authenicate users against an LDAP server. I've reviewed the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/), but there's little there to help me understand the following snippet of code:

```
profile._json.memberOf.forEach(function(e){
            if ( e === 'CN=Group 1,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com' ) user.tokens.push({ kind: '^.*$' });

            if ( e === 'CN=Group 2,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com' ) user.tokens.push({ kind: '^/security.*' });
            if ( [  'CN=Group 1,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com' ].indexOf(e) >= 0 ) {
              user.tokens.push({ kind: '^/server(/env133)?(/batch.*)?$' });
            }
            if ( [  'CN=Group 3,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com',
            'CN=Group 4,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com',
            'CN=Group 5,OU=ConfidentialGroup,DC=com' ].indexOf(e) >= 0 ) {
              user.tokens.push({ kind: '^/server(/env133)?(/batch.*)?$' });
            }
```

I would be eternally grateful if someone could explain what the above code does. I know the part following the "kind: '" is a regular expression. Beyond this, I'm a bit lost.

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a lot of info on this, here's one issue I found that is similar: https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth/issues/4 Maybe try making an issue in the repo? From what I can gather, it's looping through your authenticated profile, checking if the current `memberOf` property contains certain text and adding a regex token kind. Typically the `kind` property on a token indicates the type of token (`oauth`, `facebook`, etc.). Those regex strings are telling it to match against regex rather than describing the token type, it seems.

Comment: @rickjerrity Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.